# What does "making those loans" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does the sentence in bold mean "The banks used the money deposited by American people to lend corporations including Boeing and Ford"?

There are several reasons why the American megabanks — survivors of the last crisis in 2008 — were the main beneficiaries of the deposits bonanza. **When states began instituting shutdowns in March, corporations including Boeing and Ford immediately drew tens of billions of dollars from lines of credit, and that money was initially parked at the banks making those loans**.

Source:https://www.cnbc.com/2020/06/21/banks-have-grown-by-2-trillion-in-deposits-since-coronavirus-first-hit.html

Comment: Boeing and Ford have lines of credit, which as you know is a source of money they are permitted to borrow.  So, they borrowed the money but kept it in the bank rather than diverting it for other purposes.   Google 'revolving loans' for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much.